# Flutter Error: E/onesignal( 976): promptPermission() is not applicable in Android

Tags: flutter, onesignal

I am trying android to subscribe push notification on onesignal on flutter. 
I followed: [http://flatteredwithflutter.com/send-notifications-in-flutter/][1]

But when I go to one signal account I still see 0 subscriber. I have tried both creating new flutter and running example. But it has not been working.

Comment: Same here! Did you manage to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

Please try again by following our official [docs](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/flutter-sdk-setup).

If you are still struggling, take a look at our [troubleshooting](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/troubleshooting) guides or message us through our support channel at https://onesignal.com